# Model Validation Regex never matches

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following Regex annotation:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"(?=.{6,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})", ErrorMessage = "Password is not strong enough!")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

This is a copy/paste from my Regex I use in my MembershipProvider, where it works, as I can register with passwords like "admin1*". I tested this regex in RegexHero as well and it does work.

When I post back my form to the controller the value is also present, yet the model never validates.

Anyone have a clue as to what this could be?

Thanks in advance,

Edit:

I tested with a Regex that validates strings containing only 5 numbers, and that does validate when I input 12345, and fails with other string like "abc". So the regex mechanism seems to work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is fine, the problem is with how is the `IsValid` method implemented in the `RegularExpressionAttriubte`. Because an input will be valid only if it matches the whole pattern form the start.

An excerpt of the `IsValid` method as seen by Resharper:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
  //...
  Match match = this.Regex.Match(input);
  if (match.Success && match.Index == 0)
    return match.Length == input.Length;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Your pattern `@"(?=.{6,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})` matches the input `admin1*` so `match.Success` will be `true` but because of the usage of the [Grouping constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#matched_subexpression) the `match.Legth` will be always `0` and the `match.Length == input.Length` evaluates to always `false`.

It works in the `MembershipProvider` because it only checks for `match.Success`, and doesn't care about the length of the match.

I see two possible solution:

1. Rewrite your regex pattern to not use Grouping constructs (I'm not good at regex so I cannot help here)
2. Create your own `RegularExpressionAttriubte` (or derive from the built in one) where in the `IsValid` method you only check for `match.Success`

Comment: +1.  And it looks like you could simply replace all `(capturing)` groups with `(?:non-capturing)` groups to solve this.  So the regular expression would become `(?=.{6,})(?=(?:.*\d){1,})(?=(?:.*\W){1,})`.

Comment: This worked for me.  I added my complete code sample here: https://gist.github.com/4198259